# How can I solve issues with constructing a Django view for a small project?

Tags: python, django

Issues constructing a small project namely with the view. It doesn't give me any results and by changing some lines of codes. At this moment I can't even go from my landingpage to the next view I constructed. I was wondering if someone can help me with this kind of problem.

Under this block of text you can see the view I want to implement but I can't reach it through my landingpage anymore. On top of that i am not even sure that it will work and give me the output that i would like to have.

````
class StructurerenView(generic.TemplateView):
   template_name = 'ssc/filter.html'
   success_url = '/Definieer_zoekopdracht/results/'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       infrastructuren = ['Zonnepanelen', 'BiomassaInstallaties', 'Windturbines', 'WaterkrachtInstallaties']
       bedrijfstypes = ['Kleine onderneming', 'Middelgrote onderneming', 'Grote onderneming']
       remaining_durations = ['1 jaar', '2 jaar', '3 jaar']
       household_compositions = ['Samengesteld gezin', 'Alleenstaand', 'Alleenstaande ouder']

       # Haal de filterresultaten op
       selected_infrastructuren = self.request.GET.getlist('infrastructure')
       selected_bedrijfstypes = self.request.GET.getlist('business_type')
       selected_klasse = self.request.GET.getlist('model_class')
       remaining_length = self.request.GET.get('remaining_duration')
       samenstelling = self.request.GET.get('household_composition')

       prosumenten = Prosument.objects.filter(infrastructuur__in=selected_infrastructuren)
       bedrijven = Bedrijf.objects.filter(type__in=selected_bedrijfstypes)
       huishoudens = Huishouden.objects.filter(samenstelling=samenstelling)
       contracts = Contract.objects.filter(producent__in=selected_klasse, einddatum__gte=remaining_length)

       context['infrastructures'] = infrastructuren
       context['business_types'] = bedrijfstypes
       context['remaining_durations'] = remaining_durations
       context['household_compositions'] = household_compositions
       context['selected_infrastructuren'] = selected_infrastructuren
       context['selected_bedrijfstypes'] = selected_bedrijfstypes
       context['selected_klasse'] = selected_klasse
       context['remaining_length'] = remaining_length
       context['samenstelling'] = samenstelling
       context['prosumenten'] = prosumenten
       context['bedrijven'] = bedrijven
       context['huishoudens'] = huishoudens
       context['contracts'] = contracts

       return context```
````